# MacOS - howto change the SYSTEM temp folder (programmatically)?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

we need to change the default SYSTEM temp folder for our multiplatform application.

The systems default call for getting the SYSTEM temp folder should return the folder we have specified. On MS-Windows this is `GetTempPath()`. On MacOS the function is called `NSTemporaryDirectory()` I think.

We need to do this because we are running multiple instances of our application at the same time. There are some 3rd party libs which are using non-unique temporary filenames stored in the SYSTEMs temp folder.

For Microsoft Windows and for Unix platforms we already have a solution:

```
   Microsoft Windows:

        setenv("TMP", myOwnTempFolder);
        tmpFolderToUse=GetTempPath(); // use WinOS API call


   Unix:

         setenv("TMPDIR", myOwnTempFolder);
         tmpFolderToUse = getenv("TMPDIR");
```

but this doesn't work for MacOS(X).

```
   MacOS:

         setenv("TMPDIR", myOwnTempFolder);
         tmpFolderToUse = NSTemporaryDirectory(); // use MacOS API call
```

The call to NSTemporaryDirectory() always returns the default path afterwards (as without setting a different folder).

I have tried to invoke setenv("...") with TMPDIR, TEMP, TEMPDIR, and TMP - but no luck on MacOSX.

For clarification: here a multiple instance pseudo-code example as it currently implemented for the Windows OS flavor of our application:

instance1:

```
tmp=GetTempPath(); // -> 'C:\User\testing\temp'
uuid=getUUID(); // -> 'd7c5df40-d48d-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66'
setenv("TMP", tmp + uuid);
tmp=GetTempPath(); // --> 'C:\User\testing\temp\d7c5df40-d48d-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66'
```

instance2:

```
tmp=GetTempPath(); // -> 'C:\User\testing\temp'
uuid=getUUID(); // -> '435aeb10-d48e-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66'
setenv("TMP", tmp + uuid);
tmp=GetTempPath(); // --> 'C:\User\testing\temp\435aeb10-d48e-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66'
```

How do we achieve the same behavior on MacOS?

Comment: Since you have a specific directory in mind, can you just use that rather than calling NSTemporaryDirectory?

Comment: no, unfortunately not. Our application makes use of some third party libraries and these 3rd party libs are calling NSTemporaryDirectory() to get the SYSTEM temp folder

Comment: >> Why would you do this?
we have multiple instances of our application. The 3rd party libs we are using create some files which will be overwritten my another instance. So the idea is to create a unique temp folder to avoid this kind of a race condition.

Comment: Won't this just replace one race condition with another if you're changing the global setting that'll affect all instances?

Comment: Why, exactly, do you need to change the location of the temporary items folder? What's wrong with the one Cocoa gives you by default?

Comment: >> Won't this just replace one race condition with another if you're changing the global setting that'll affect all instances? 
no. Each instance creates a unique temporary folder

>> why do you need to change the location of the temporary items folder?
It's because we have multiple instances of the application running simultaneously. On Windows/Unix each of these instances use a separate SYSTEM temp folder.

Comment: You're missing my point. Changing the global temporary directory does add a race condition. If one instance changes the temp directory, attempts to write to the new unique location, but another instance changes the temp directory before the write occurs, you'll have troubles.

Comment: That cannot happen, because - and for example:

instance1: get default TEMP location and add a UUID
instance2: get default TEMP location and add a UUID

and thats exactly the way it currently work fine on Windows and Unix OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSTemporaryDirectory()` uses `confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR)`, not `$TMPDIR`.  I don't know of an API to *set* `confstr(3)`s, so I think you'll need to override either `NSTemporaryDirectory` or `confstr$UNIX2003` with [`DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) or a similar mechanism.

But really, this is a tremendous hack; your application should not assume it is the only instance running in the temporary directory if this is not the case.  It should do its own uniquing with `mkdtemp(3)` or similar.

Comment: You are right. Hacking with confstr or with DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES is not an option.

So for MacOS I will try a workaround for getting the tmp folder: return the value of TMPDIR if it is set, otherwise return the value as provided by NSTemporaryDirectory. But this still has the disadvantage that the used 3rd party libs will not make use of TMPDIR.

Comment: ... we have implemented this now. As expected this approach is working well for our own application/our own libraries. But not for the 3rd party libs used by our application.

Comment: I would say external lib is bad-written and/or not portable.